# riak 2.0.5 doesnt start with bad_return_value,{error,einval}

Tags: riak

When trying to start riak server, it failed to start, by running

```
riak console
```

it shows

> Erlang R16B02_basho6 (erts-5.10.3) [source-bcd8abb] [64-bit] [smp:4:4]
>   [async-threads:64] [kernel-poll:true] [frame-pointer]
>
> [os_mon] memory supervisor port (memsup): Erlang has closed [os_mon]
>   cpu supervisor port (cpu_sup): Erlang has closed {"Kernel pid
>   terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,riak_api,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,\"pb://\"lab-vault.aspirapps.com\":8087\",{bad_return_value,{error,einval}}}},{riak_api_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

here is the riak.config (partial)

```
## 
## Acceptable values:
##   - an IP/port pair, e.g. 127.0.0.1:10011
listener.http.internal = lab-vault.aspirapps.com:8098

## listener.protobuf.<name> is an IP address and TCP port that the Riak
## Protocol Buffers interface will bind.
## 
## Default: 127.0.0.1:8087
## 
## Acceptable values:
##   - an IP/port pair, e.g. 127.0.0.1:10011
listener.protobuf.internal = lab-vault.aspirapps.com:8087

## The maximum length to which the queue of pending connections
## may grow. If set, it must be an integer > 0. If you anticipate a
## huge number of connections being initialized *simultaneously*, set
## this number higher.
## 
## Default: 128
## 
## Acceptable values:
##   - an integer
## protobuf.backlog = 128

## listener.https.<name> is an IP address and TCP port that the Riak
## HTTPS interface will bind.
## 
## Acceptable values:
##   - an IP/port pair, e.g. 127.0.0.1:10011
## listener.https.internal = lab-vault.aspirapps.com:8088
```

tried to replace url names with IP but no luck, it appears same error message.

How do I get riak up and running? Thanks.

Comment: Check /var/log/riak/* to see if there are more meaningful messages.

Comment: `## Acceptable values:
##   - an IP/port pair, e.g. 127.0.0.1:10011` - hostname or DNS name is not accepted there.

Comment: @Joe Thanks, but still have no luck with IP address.

Comment: @vempo I am working on it.

Answer (score 1):

Just get it worked.
Thanks Joe and Vempo for help to indicate possible solutions.

I have to use IP address to bind the listening IP and Port.
The additional step after revise the riak.conf file are removing previous generated configuration files

```
rm -f /var/lib/riak/ring/*
rm -f /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/*
```

thanks you all.